# How to show $\mathbb{Z}[w]/(2,w) \simeq \mathbb{Z}_2$?

Tags: ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $\mathbb{Z}[w]=\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1+\sqrt{-15}}{2}]$ be the quadratic integers.

I want to show that $\mathbb{Z}[w]/(2,w) \simeq \mathbb{Z}_2$. It seems very clear, but how can I show the isomorphism rigorously by isomorphism? I found somewhat similar using 3rd isomorphism theorem([here](http://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2010/11/13/prove-that-a-given-ideal-is-prime/)). But I think there will be much easier way.

I tried $\mathbb{Z}[w]/(2,w) \simeq (\mathbb{Z}(X)/(f(X))/(2+f(X),X+f(X))$ but I'm not sure then it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}(X)/(2,X)\simeq \mathbb{Z}_2$.

I also tried $\mathbb{Z}[X] \to \mathbb{Z}[w] \to \mathbb{Z}[w]/(2,w)$, but not sure what the kernel is. Obviousely $2,w$ goes to $0$ but isn't it possible that $1 \mapsto 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's not obvious that $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(2,X) \cong \mathbb{F}_2$, then quotient out by one element at a time:

$$ \mathbb{Z}[X]/(2,X) = \left( \mathbb{Z}[X] / (2) \right) / (X) $$

or

$$ \mathbb{Z}[X]/(2,X) = \left( \mathbb{Z}[X] / (X) \right) / (2) $$

and maybe it will be easier.

Comment: This looks good. $\mathbb{Z}[X] \to \mathbb{Z}[X]/(2,X)$ induces $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X) \to \mathbb{Z}[X]/(2,X)$, and this map has kernel $(2+(X))$, so it induces isomorphism $(\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X))/(2+(X)) \to \mathbb{Z}[X]/(2,X)$. Also under the isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X) \to \mathbb{Z}$, $2+(X)$ is mapped to $2$ so we have an isomorphism to $\mathbb{Z}/(2)$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: Define:

$$
\varphi(a + b \omega) = \begin{cases} 0 &: a \text{ even} \\
1 &: a \text{ odd}
\end{cases}
$$

Show that this is a homomorphism from $\Bbb Z[\omega]$ to $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ and find its kernel. Apply the first isomorphism theorem.

Answer (score 3):

Denoting $\,\Bbb Z_p:=$ the prime field of characteristic $\,p\,$ , try to follow and prove the following:

$$\Bbb Z[w]/(2,w)\cong\left(\Bbb Z[w]/(2)\right)/\left((2,w)/(2)\right)\cong\Bbb Z_2[w]/(w)\cong\Bbb Z_2$$

Comment: In the middle, do you mean that $Z[w] \to Z_2[w]/(w)$ induces $Z[w]/(2) \to Z_2[w]/(w)$, and then induces $(Z[w]/(2))/(2,w)/(2)) \to Z_2[w]/(w)$?

Comment: What I meant in the middle is $$\Bbb Z[w]/(2)\cong\Bbb Z_2[w]\;,\;\;(2,w)/(2)\cong (2)$$ I'm not sure though whether this is what you meant, but if this is understood then the pass from the middle to the right is just the third (or second) isomorphism theorem, and the last isomorphism is trivial.

Comment: I thought of it, but is it okay to say $(2,w)/(2)\simeq (2)$? $(2,w)$ is not a ring, it's just an ideal. I'm not sure "quotient of an ideal" and "isomorphism of ideals" is valid. And what I'm also concerned is that in group, $Z/4Z \not\simeq Z/2Z$ even though $Z\simeq 2Z \simeq 4Z$. Doesn't it occur something like this for rings?

Comment: http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Series-equivalent_not_implies_automorphic

Comment: Well, I see it as follows: any ideal is a ring (the other way around is generally false), always without a unit if the ideal is proper, of course, so $\,I/J\,$ is well defined, both as quotient ring and/or as group. Second, I can't see where did I use anything similar to what you mention in your last two lines...?

Comment: Oh my god, I misread it. Isn't it true that $(2,w)/(2) \simeq (w)$? I just saw it as $\Bbb Z[w]/(2)\cong\Bbb Z_2[w],(2,w)/(2)\cong (w)$ so $(\Bbb Z[w]/(2))/(2,w) \cong \Bbb Z_2[w]/(w)$. I'm actually not understanding how did you use third(or second) isomorphism theorem from the middle to right.

Comment: What I did there is to use the following: 

if $\;\phi:R\to S\;$ is a ring isomorphism s.t. $\;\phi(I)=J\;$ , for ideals $\,I\le R\,,\,J\le S\;$ , then we have an isomorphism of quotient rings $\bar\phi:R/I\to S/J\;$ , which follows from the first isom. theorem applied at the homomorphism $$\overline \phi :R\to S/J\;,\;\;\overline \phi(r):=\phi(r)+J$$

Comment: I had a similar question to this and this response was insightful. I follow all of the steps except for the very first isomorphism. It looks like the 3rd isomorphism theorem but (2) isn't an ideal in $Z[w]$. Do you mind elaborating on how you arrived at the first iso from above? Again, this helped me see this problem clearer other than this snag.